# callback to class from quartz job

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, quartz.net

I have different classes as descendants of a base class (Worker).
Each of these classes has it's own quartz job and trigger and a
callback.

```
public class Worker1 : Worker, ICallback
{
    IScheduler scheduler;
    public Worker1(IScheduler scheduler)
        : base("Worker1")
    {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonitorJob>()
            .WithIdentity(name + "Job")
            .Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(name + "Trigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    public void Callback()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " callback " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }
}
```

Now I want on trigger of job1 (from worker1) a callback to worker1.callback.
Same with job2 (from worker2) a callback to worker2.callback.

With autofac I am able to inject a callback into my job - however I can only inject a common callback, not as I like one for each class.

```
public class MonitorJob : IJob
{
    ICallback callback;

    public MonitorJob(ICallback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        callback.Callback();
    }
}
```

my main class creates the autofac container

```
 container = ConfigureContainer(new ContainerBuilder()).Build();
 using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
 {
      workers.Add(container.Resolve<Worker1>());
      workers.Add(container.Resolve<Worker2>());
 }
 var factory = container.Resolve<ISchedulerFactory>();
 var scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
 scheduler.Start();

 internal static ContainerBuilder ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder cb)
 {
      cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
      cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(typeof(QuartzScheduler.MonitorJob).Assembly));
      cb.RegisterType<Worker1>().AsSelf();
      cb.RegisterType<Worker2>().AsSelf();
      return cb;
  }
```

Autofac creates the job and also could inject it with a callback, however I want the right callback from the worker class that "owns" the job.

How would this be possible?

Otherwise I would need to somehow propagate from one common callback to the respective worker class.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded by creating a generic job:

```
public class MonitorJob<T> : IJob where T:IWorker
{
    T worker;

    public MonitorJob(T worker)
    {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        worker.Callback();
    }
}
```

In my custom worker class I create the monitor job for this worker:

```
public Worker1(IScheduler scheduler)
{
   this.scheduler = scheduler;

   IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonitorJob<Worker1>>()
      .WithIdentity(name + "Job")
      .Build();
        [...]
 }
```

and so the right callback class will be resolved by:

```
container.RegisterType<Worker1>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
container.RegisterType<MonitorJob<Worker1>>().AsSelf();

[...]
workers.Add(scope.Resolve<Worker1>());
```

so always the right callback is executed for each individual job.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac has no way to know how to *bind* `ICallback` and `IJob`. How would like to bind them ?

The simplest solution is to introduce a dependency between these 2 classes

```
public class MonitorJob : IJob
{
    public MonitorJob(Worker1 worker1)
    {
        this._worker1 = worker1;
    }

    private readonly Worker1 _worker1;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        this._worker1.Callback();
    }
}
```

If it is not possible you can use [Keyed service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) :

```
public class MonitorJob : IJob
{
    public MonitorJob([WithKey("Worker1")]ICallback callback)
    {
        this._callback = callback;
    }

    private readonly ICallback _callback;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        this._callback.Callback();
    }
}
```

and you will have to register it this way `cb.RegisterType<Worker1>().Keyed<ICallback>("Worker1")`

If it is still not possible to modify your code this way, you can create a new module to add parameters :

```
public class CallbackModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        if (registration.Services.OfType<TypedService>()
                                 .Any(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(IJob)))
        {
            registration.Preparing += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // bind ICallback and IJob here
                if (registration.Activator.LimitType == typeof(Job1))
                {
                    e.Parameters = e.Parameters
                                    .Concat(new TypedParameter[] { TypedParameter.From<ICallback>(e.Context.Resolve<Worker1>()) });
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And the registration can be made this way :

```
    ContainerBuilder cb = new ContainerBuilder();
    cb.RegisterModule(new CallbackModule());
    cb.RegisterType<Worker1>().As<ICallback>().AsSelf();
    cb.RegisterType<Worker2>().As<ICallback>().AsSelf();
    IContainer container = cb.Build();
```

---

By the way, the following code contains a mistake:

```
using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  workers.Add(container.Resolve<Worker1>());
  workers.Add(container.Resolve<Worker2>());
}
```

You create a new ILifetimeScope but don't use it. The following code should be use instead :

```
using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  workers.Add(scope.Resolve<Worker1>());
  workers.Add(scope.Resolve<Worker2>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, however binding ICallback to IJob already worked, as mentioned in my question - but of course only for one callback instance, where I would have to propagate the event to the respective worker instance. 
I don't want to couple it directly to worker1, because it should also trigger other worker instances, e.g. worker2.callback up to workerN.
Therefore I think the Keyed approach won't fit either.
I could create a job per worker derived from my generic MonitorJob which could be resolved  but I was hoping it would be possible by a generic approach.

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood your needs. When `MonitorJob` is triggered which `ICallback` should be used ? All of them ? if so, you can add a dependency on `IEnumerable<ICallback>` if you want a specific one, how do you specify which `ICallback` an `IJob` should use ?

Comment: each worker has it's own monitorjob which should call it's own callback. I succeeded by deriving an Worker1Job from Monitorjob which has the worker class with clallback in it as you suggested. Downside is I need a job for each worker class. however this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified when the execute method is called, you can implement a [JobListener](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/?topic=html/357f5326-4298-2f44-c7f0-312ba50ad167.htm) for this. You can create one listener for all jobs or multiple listeners, one per job type perhaps, and then apply the appropriate matcher. Here's a link that might be useful with more details on job listeners and listeners in general: [Quartz.Net Job Listeners, Part 3 of Quartz.net Listeners in detail](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2014/12/03/quartz-net-job-listeners-part-3-of-quartz-net-listeners-in-detail/)